# Family of circles denoted by inscribed angle on a segment

Tags: circles

> For family of circles whose inscribed angle makes an angle of $ \theta$ with a line segment is given as:
> [image]
> If the coordinate of $E=(x_1,y_1)$ and of $B=(x_2,y_2)$ then the family of circles for which $EBH$ makes an angle $\theta$ (here 53) is given as:
> $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2) + (y-y_1)(y-y_2) \pm \cot \theta \left[ (x-x_1)(y-y_2) - (x-x_2)(y-y_1)\right]$$

This result was given a JEE book (Famous Indian engineering exam) with no explanation why this is true, could any one shed light on why this formula represents what it is supposed to?

Comment: @Pravimish all points standing on the same arc make the same angle for a given circle of radius, look up inscribed angle theorem. Else, explain why you think it's wrong

Comment: sry for the confusion, ihave deleted the comment

Comment: Also, can u give some clarity on the following thought. U have a fixed line segment EB. If this always forms an angle of $53^{\circ}$, then isnt there only one possible triangle, ergo, one possible circle.

Comment: take a point further outside, that would make a different angle while standing on the same arc, no? Now apply the inscribed angle thinking to that point as well @Pravimish